# Is there a difference between an immediately invoked function expression and a corresponding plain function invocation?

Tags: javascript

Is there a difference bteween an immediately invoked function expression like

```
(function () {
  angular.module("realestateApp", []);
}());
```

and a plain function invocation like

```
angular.module("realestateApp", []);
```

or are they equivalent?

Answer (score 4):

Not in this example no...

There might be, if you create a variable (or a function or a object) , that will end up in the global namespace.

```
var x = 'foo';
```

will pollute the global namespace, while:

```
(function(){
    var x = 'foo';
})();
```

won't.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it is no difference, but generally if you create some functions or variables in your code, IIFE gives you encapsulation form global namespace.

IIFE is often use to create module:

http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html